# OSX - installer fails when run from command line

Tags: macos, installation

I am trying to install our product on Mac from command line:

```
$ installer -package /Volumes/setup.pkg/setup.pkg -target /Volumes/MacOS -verbose
installer: Package name is Foo
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: Preparing for installation….....
installer: Preparing the disk….....
installer: Preparing Foo….....
installer: Waiting for other installations to complete….....
installer: Configuring the installation….....
installer:  
installer: Writing files….....
#
installer: Writing files….....
#
installer: Writing files….....
#
installer: Moving items into place….....
##
installer: The upgrade failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)
```

Everything is fine when run from GUI. `sudo` does not help. How do I debug this? At least I need a more informative log. Will be much obliged.

**Additional info since the original posting:** When run from GUI the app is installed into ${HOME}/Library of the user who runs it (as it is supposed to). When run from command line it tries to install it into /Library (and even copies some of the files there, but not everything).

Comment: I notice the "-target /Volumes/MacOS" argument, and the fact that the log is "Upgrading at base path /". When you run it in the GUI, does the volume "MacOS" show up in the list of target choices—and, if you select it, does it actually install there instead of into /?

Comment: @abarnert, (1) I'm away from work until Monday and won't be able to check if the volume is included (2) When run from GUI it installs the app into ${HOME}/Library of the user who runs it (as it is supposed to). When run from command line it tries to install it into /Library (and even copies some of the files there before croaking). I'll add this info to the question.

Comment: Well, first, why are you passing -target /Volumes/MacOS if you want it installed into ${HOME}?

Comment: @abarnert, `-target` option specifies the volume, not the installation directory. See [installer man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/installer.8.html).

Comment: Yes, and ${HOME} is not generally going to be on /Volume/MacOS. If you've renamed your boot drive from the default to MacOS, then that will be a symlink to /, so it should work. Or, if you've moved your home directory onto some other drive, or various other cases. But still, why are you providing it at all?

Comment: Can you xar the .pkg file and show the Distribution file? That's the only way to really see what it's trying to do.

Comment: @abarnert `-target CurrentUserHomeDirectory` did the trick. As the discussion with you helped me to pinpoint the problem - if you answer the question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the GUI, you're not explicitly specifying a target, so everything goes where the package wants to put it. But on the command line, you're explicitly specifying `-target /Volumes/MacOS`, which is overriding what the package has specified, so it's trying to put files inside `/Library` and presumably other places, some of which you don't have access to.

Apparently `-target CurrentUserHomeDirectory` solves the problem.

To get any further detail, you need to extract the package (the easiest way to do that is `xar -xf setup.pkg` in an empty directory) and look at the files Distribution, */PackageInfo, and possibly */Bom, to see what exactly the installer is specifying. But if you just want it to work, you already know how to do that.

Comment: *Leaving off -target entirely might also work.* It does not - I've tried it.